# Future sequence to sequence of futures?

Tags: scala, future

Suppose, I have an abstract "producer" instance:

```
  trait Producer[T] {
    def listObjectIds: Future[Seq[String]]
    def getObject(id: String): Future[T]
  }
```

and I need to apply some processing to each (or some) of the objects it yields. 
So, I do something like:

```
  producer
    .listObjectIds
    .map(maybeFilter)
    .map(_.map(producer.getObject))
```

... and end up with `Future[Seq[Future[T]]]`
This is ok, but kinda cumbersome. I would like to get rid of the outer `Future`, and just have `Seq[Future[T]]`, but can't think of a (non-blocking) transformation, that would let me do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to end up with a `Seq[Future[T]]`. See [Reverse of Future.sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45045419/854793).

But it is possible to end with a `Future[Seq[T]]`. Just call `.flatMap(Future.sequence)` on the `Future[Seq[Future[T]]`.

Comment: Yeah, I know ... I don't what that though. My `Seq` is lazy (it's actually an `Iterator`, not even `Seq`), and the idea is to load those objects one-by-one. They won't even fit into memory more than a couple of so at a time. I understand your point about not knowing how long the result is going to be, but I'd be fine with `Iterator[Future[T]]`, that always ends with a failure (kinda like `Future.collect` does when the PF is not defined).

Comment: What should happen if `.next` was called on the iterator 1000 times immediately, and eventually the `Future[Seq]` finished with just 1 element? The other 999 would all end in failure?

Comment: Yes. So, we get 1000 futures. The first one satisfies with the result of `getObject`. All the other ones end up throwing `NoSuchElementException` when satisfied ... Just like `Future(1).collect { case 2 => "two" }` would do.

Comment: Then perhaps something like: `Iterator.from(0).map(i => futSeqFut.flatMap(s => s(i)))` ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that ... except, that, again, it's really not a `Seq`, but an `Iterator` (sorry, I should have mentioned it upfront, but didn't realize, that was this important ... tried too hard to simplify). There are hundreds of thousands of elements, I don't want fetch them all into a buffer just to visit each one once.

Comment: Then `listObjectIds` would have to return something other than a `Future[Seq]`. It's sounding more and more like you might want to consider modeling this using some streaming library (akka streams or fs2)

Comment: It returns`Future[Stream]` (which is a kind of `Seq`), and I swap it for `Iterator` first thing after with `.map(_.iterator)`. Not sure how akka would help here.